# Styleable 3D vector graphics format?

Tags: css, svg, 3d, vector-graphics

If I want to draw some 2D geometric primitives I can use svg format and style them through css. What if I want to do the same things in 3D?

Comment: you can use CSS 3D transforms wih SVG in most UAs.

Comment: This way you can't insert primiteves from 3d data. This is want I want: draw a path with x,y,z data like I do in 2D svg.

Comment: SVG is not suitable for that, it's basically a 2d technology. You could try researching webgl.

Comment: Yes, I know that I could use webgl but I don't think is a 3d equivalent of svg. For example I could not style through css or something similar.

Comment: I don't think what you want exists then.